# headerd include each other in c++

Tags: c++, header

I have an error while I am trying to do this:

in main.cpp file -

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Image.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace imaging;

int main()
{
    char onoma_arxeiou[100];
    cout<<"Dwse onoma arxeiou: ";
    cin>>onoma_arxeiou;

    Image im(5,6);
    im<<onoma_arxeiou;
}
```

Image.h

```
 #include "ppm_format.h"

using namespace std;

namespace imaging
{
    class Image
    {
        bool Image::operator << (std::string filename)
        {
           ReadPPM(filename.c_str());
        }
    };
```

and ppm.h

```
class Image;
//#include "Image.h"

namespace imaging
{
    void ReadPPM(const char * filename);

    bool WritePPM(Image & image, const char * filename);

}
```

but in `main` can't see `Image` having these errors:

> error: reference to ‘Image’ is ambiguous

```
Image im(5,6);
```

any help please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: In `ppm.h` put `class Image;` inside the namespace.

Comment: thnk u very much!! ))

Comment: So which ones are the headers that include each other? You haven't shown any.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this fails in `ppm.h` you have a forward declaration for Image:

```
class Image;
```

however this is in the global namespace and not in your `imaging` namespace.

To fix this put your forward declaration inside the `imaging` namespace.

```
namespace imaging
{
  class Image;

  void ReadPPM(const char * filename);

  /// ...

}
```

Comment: thnk u very much. but if i will try to create an Image inside ReadPPM(const char * filename){ Image im} i failed? why did happen?

Comment: Put the implementation of ReadPPM() in a source file instead of the header. In that source file include `Image.h`.

Comment: Hi i did that. i dont have any error except that:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lomnvt3jmlyzo58/%CE%9A%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B1%CE%B3%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%86%CE%AE.JPG?dl=0

Comment: My advice is to ask a new question about the Image class showing the class declaration for Image and also include the errors as text. It looks like you are defining the class members for Image in the header instead of the cpp file.